# regular expression in Linux

Tags: grep

I wrote a code which gets a file and checks with egrep how many times the word appear. For example:
h1 contains:

```
shalom1 def ab1 hello abc
yab
hi def
```

The code :

```
egrep -c "[ |^]hi[ |$]" h1
```

should appear 1
but the output is 0
or when I try

```
egrep -c "[ |^]abc[ |$]" h1
```

should appear 1
the output is 0
why?

Comment: I tried doing egrep -c "ab" h1 but it also counts ab1 If I try it  with hi or abc or hello no problem there. I need to count how many times the word appears in a file .like how many times the word ab appears in the file h1 but it didn't work with the code that I wrote.

Comment: what does egrep -c "\bab\b" do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the word "hi" at the beginning of the line or end of the line or surrounded by spaces and count the number of lines where it appears:

```
$ egrep -c "(^|[[:space:]]+)hi([[:space:]]+|$)" h1
1
```

But the -w option does the same job to match words:

```
$ egrep -w "hi" h1
hi def
```

So to count the number of lines where the word appears:

```
$ egrep -wc "hi" h1
1
```

Comment: I tried egrep -c "(^|[[ ]]+)hi([[ ]]+|$) but the output is still 0 . Did I write it wrong?

Comment: you must explicitly write "space" (cf. [man 7 regex](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html))

Comment: You mean write it exactly like this: egrep -c "(^|[[:space:]]+)hi([[:space:]]+|$)"?

Comment: Yes. But this will give the number of lines where the word appears not the number of times the word appears.